# Find $c_i$ that minimizes $\left\Vert \mathbf{x} - \sum_i c_i \mathbf{x}_i \right\Vert_0$

Tags: linear-algebra

Given $k$ linearly independent vectors $\mathbf{x}_1 \ldots , \mathbf{x}_k$ and $\mathbf{x}$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, $k<n$, find the "best" linear combination

$$\sum_{i=1}^k c_i \mathbf{x}_i \tag 1$$

of the first $k$ vectors, that minimizes the $\ell_0$-norm* of the difference between $\mathbf{x}$ and (1).

(*) The $\ell_0$-norm is the number of non-zero components.

Comment: Minimizing the number of nonzero components of a vector is known as $\ell_0$-norm minimization.

Comment: @Rahul Thanks. I edited the question.

Comment: @becko I doubt that you can solve this problem exactly and efficiently for generic $\mathbf{x}_i$s. Also, if $k$ is much smaller than $n$ you cannot hope for very sparse difference. Similar problems are studied in *analysis compressed sensing*.

Comment: @S.B. The $\mathbf{x}$'s are all very sparse. Would that help?

Comment: @becko You can eliminate the coordinates where all $x_i$s and $x$ are simultaneously zero as they don't have any effect in the $\ell_0$. Would that make your vectors dense? In the end, I think it all depends on the particular vectors you have.

Comment: @S.B. There are no coordinates where *all* the vectors are zero. There are no "superfluous" coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

If the vector is in the span of the basis then you may use the least squares solution and the $\ell_0$ norm will be zero. In the case when it is not in the span - then there will be infinitely many solutions that give the same $\ell_0$ norm. You might consider the so-called ['greedy methods'](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/222560342_Algorithms_for_simultaneous_sparse_approximation._Part_I_Greedy_pursuit/file/9c96052a4e9b6b718a.pdf) - in which case you should at least be able to achieve $\left\Vert \mathbf{x} - \sum_i c_i \mathbf{x}_i \right\Vert_0 \le n-k$.  [Compressive Sensing](ftp://ftp.math.ucla.edu/pub/camreport/cam08-37.pdf)  approaches (replacing $\ell_0$ with $\ell_1$ to maintain convexity) are interesting - but really designed for the case where you have more unknowns than equations - not this case.